# No Ransack Search object was provided to search_form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I'm using the ransack gem, and it can't seem to find the search object, even though it's in my controller.

This is the index method

```
  def index
      if params[:q].present?
       @search = Patient.search(params[:q])
       @patients = @search.result
      else
       @patients = Patient.where(:user_id => params[:user_id])
      end
  end
```

This is the view form

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :name_cont, "Name" %>
                    <%= f.text_field :name_cont %>
                </div>
                  <div><%= f.submit %></div>
            <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are conditionally setting search based on `params[:q]` which will never get generated because it relies on the form in your view.

I would revise your code in your controller like this

```
def index 
  @search = Patient.search(params[:q])
  @patients = @search.result
  if params[:q].blank?
    @patients = Patient.where(:user_id => params[:user_id])
  end
end
```

This way, you get your search prioritized if it's available, otherwise you scope it down to how you want it.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
   <%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
```

with

```
   <%= search_form_for @search, url: url_for(controller: 'users', action: 'index') do |f| %>
```

Replace the controller name with your own controller

Comment: I'm still getting the same error => No Ransack::Search object was provided to search_form_for!

Answer (score -1):

Not a very clean solution but you could basically precheck if !@search.blank? in your view.

```
<% if (!@search.blank?) %>
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name_cont, "Name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name_cont %>
  </div>
  <div><%= f.submit %></div>`enter code here`
<% end %>
```